# Control flow - Jump to another loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, goto

I did not find any duplicates of this question, i understand that Python has no "goto" functionality in itself and how i can make use of "continue" in a loop to get the same effect, but i'm not really sure if it's any recommended method of "jumping back" to another loop for eg? Let me show you an example below

```
while True:
    print("Hey! Some text.. blablah")
    x = input("You wanna continue? (yes/no) ")
    if x == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        print("End of loop")
        break
        
while True:
    print("Hey! Some more text, blablah even more")
    x = input("You wanna continue? (yes/no): ")
    if x == "yes":
        continue
    elif x == "no":
        print("End of program")
        break
    else:
        pass
        # Here i would want to be able to send the user back to the 1st loop if user gives any other input than "yes" or "no"
```

The only thing i can think of right now that makes any sense (to not have to simply rewrite the whole thing again) is to simply set the first loop to a function and call that from the second loop to get the result i want, this works as i intend it to:

```
def firstloop():
    while True:
        print("Hey! Some text.. blablah")
        x = input("You wanna continue? (yes/no) ")
        if x == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            print("End of loop")
            break
            
firstloop()
        
while True:
    print("Hey! Some more text, blablah even more")
    x = input("You wanna continue? (yes/no): ")
    if x == "yes":
        continue
    elif x == "no":
        print("End of program")
        break
    else:
        firstloop()
```

But somehow it feels like i'm over complicating something, or is this the "best" way i can go by with something like this? Thanks

Comment: When it comes to "come back" to run snippet code, the only way that I've seen is using a function

Comment: Shouldn't it be an error to answer something other than `yes` or `no`? Why does it go back to `firstloop()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was probably a bad example but this was just a sample to illustrate what i meant, the focus of the question was meant to be the "going back" between the loops. But in a real program i would of course use some other trigger than any random input for this :)

Comment: Generally if you want to go back to something, put it in a loop. You would have a loop that encompassed the code you wanted to go back through.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the second loop inside the first one (or inside an enclosing while for both).  GOTOs are never needed,  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming